# MSAL with Shared Device Mode + dependencies

Tags: android, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

my company wants to implement SSO on an Android device, which is used by several employees over the day. We came accross MSAL and the use of the Authenticator App to implement SSO. As far as I understood, I need to put the device into "Shared Device Mode".

From what I read so far I am confused, if I therefor also need to use Intune to manage my Android device. Currently, we use another Mobile Device Management solution.

Can someone clarify to me, if I can use MSAL for SSO on an Android device in a Shared Device scenarion without using Intune?

I am very confused at the moment.

Best regards,
Marcel

Comment: @Deep, thank you for your insight. I also found this sites and was upset that I can't use it. In the meantime, I found the following site:

https://www.anoopcnair.com/azure-ad-shared-device-mode-intune-with-joy/

This states, that I can use Shared Device mode. I already tested it with the Authenticator, but I would like to verfiy the login/logout with a test app. This is still ongoing, but I will post my results here. (Maybe someone will come accross the same question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   `Yes, you can configure and use MSAL for SSO on an Android device in a shared device scenario` without using Intune by following the below given documentation link. It clearly describes the steps for `enabling shared-device mode for an android application and integrating MSAL with it for signing in and signing out a user`.

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-shared-device-mode***

[image: Azure AD App registration]

[image: Android app settings]

The above snapshots depict the **MSAL authentication integration for an Android platform-based application in Azure AD** and the associated **‘auth_config.json’** `file configuration in the application setup files in which the Azure AD application registration details are configured`. It also states that the shared device mode is supported for the MSAL authentication with SSO.

Comment: Thank you, @KartikBhiwapurkur ! This is excatley what I found out after futher research and can also confirm by my finished tests. :)